# 20.04 should I use snap or apt?

Tags: apt, snap

I have updated from 19.10 to 20.04 and have been using gnome-logs to check everything is working ok. In fact I have posted here about a couple of warnings, so I am 100% sure it has been working in 20.04. Then today gnome-logs didn't start from the dash so I called it from the console and got this message:

> $ gnome-logs
>
> Der Befehl 'gnome-logs' wurde nicht gefunden, kann aber installiert
>   werden mit:
>
> sudo snap install gnome-logs  # version 3.34.0, or sudo apt  install
>   gnome-logs  # version 3.34.0-1ubuntu1

(The German reads "The command 'gnome-logs' was not found but can be installed with: .......)

I have no idea how or why it  it disappeared but I reinstalled it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-logs` and the version 3.34.0 was installed and works as it did previously. If anyone has an idea of why gnome-logs just disappeared I love to know why, but for now my main question is this:

Is it advantageous for me to use snap? I have plenty of room on my hard-drive and I understand (and being happy with apt I haven't really studied it) that snap doesn't share libraries among programs but installs libraries for exclusive use by each program. I can see the pros and cons of this but have never had a problem with Ubuntu using apt. Is there any good reason for me to start installing via snap? And if I start now won't I have a mongrel system with apt and snap apps and programs which could lead to problems later on?

Edit: How would I know, as an end user, which from apt or snap is best for each need. Why did the system recommend a snap for gnome-logs? Is the system helping me decide which installation app to use, or simply choosing snap for everything from now on?

Comment: The repositories for Ubuntu come with set versions of packages, 19.10/eoan will have one set of packages, focal/20.04 will have another.  The apt/deb packages will use that specific version, however snaps may allow to use a different version to what is packaged for your release.  Some snaps can share libraries (shared snaps) however that's rather limited and most end-user apps won't use that feature (mainly used by system snaps built for it).  Snaps tend to load slower (on first run), can use more memory (not always though), the best mostly varies on which is best for each need.

Comment: Also, when you *bump* releases from 19.10 to 20.04, all apt/deb packages need to be upgraded; the snaps are release independent (probably exceptions to this general rule though) so they won't get upgraded.. ie. focal would run the same snap as eoan would.

Comment: @ guiverc Thanks. But how would I know, as an end user, which is best for each need. Why did the system recommend a snap for gnome-logs? Is the system helping me decide which installation app to use, or simply choosing snap for everything from now on?

Comment: `gnome-logs` is a deb package for my system (groovy or what will be 20.10; it won't have changed since i was on 20.04/focal I bet either).   I `whereis gnome-logs` then `dpkg -S` to get it was from `gnome-logs` package. Personally I decide myself & `apt install` or `snap install` (usually opting for deb's).  My usual need/reason for *snap* is because a *deb* isn't available (or is a hassle for some reason), OR i need a specific version that the *deb* version won't give me.